# While submitting transaction no ledger context error in hyperledger chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I am converting a certificate signing request to self signed certificate using hyper ledger chaincode. But while storing information regarding the certificate, transaction is not being successful and it gives me no ledger context error.

Nodejs version : 8.9.4

My chaincode function is:

```
async registerDomain(ctx, csr) {
let buff = new Buffer(csr, 'base64')
let csrData = buff.toString('ascii')
pem.createPrivateKey(2048, {
    aes128: "11223344"
}, async function (err, pk) {
    let domain = new Domain(ctx, "abcd", "data.detail", "keys.certificate", "pk.key");
    await ctx.stub.putState(domain.domainId, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(domain)));
});
```

While transaction this is what I am getting inside peer docker logs:

> HandleTransaction -> ERRO 09f [ddc81d1b] Failed to handle PUT_STATE. error: no ledger context
>   runtime.goexit
>       /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1333
>   PUT_STATE failed: transaction ID: ddc81d1bcb69eecd6c6bbcf85ba16b2168486d4b232ef3c03fe5bbc7bb2adea1
>   github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.
>   runtime.goexit

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Is the issue fixed. Could you please tell me as I'm also stuck with this error for long time?

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced a similar issue. Though there is no any proper solution for this error.
As per my understanding, this error is thrown when tx takes more time to complete and lose the context instance provided by state db api's.

In your example, createPrivateKey might be taking more time to generate pk and thus causing "no ledger context" issue.

Reference:
https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-17512?focusedCommentId=69269&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-69269